# cURL times out when online but not on localhost

Tags: php, curl, localhost

I have this curl code that should allow me to grab the text from 411.com.
When I test this out using wamp on my localhost, the code works perfectly but when I test it online i get the error connection timed out.

My website uses ssl. Not sure if that matters.

```
<?php     
//$url = "http://www.411.com/phone/1-310-402-9829";
$url = "www.411.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36'); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
{
$pos = stripos($string, $start);

$str = substr($string, $pos);

$str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));

$second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);

$str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);

$unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces

return $unit;
}

$unit = extract_unit($output, '<span class="subtitle block pull-left">', 'in');

// Outputs: acronym
echo $unit;
?>
```

Comment: Your hosting service might have a firewall that's blocking the connection.

Comment: @Barmar I just contacted my hosting service and they told me that 411.com is blocking their IP. what can i do about this? Use a proxy?

Comment: Yeah, that will probably work.

Comment: @Barmar Got it to work thanks so much. Feel free to make a post and ill like it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this is that my website was not able to access 411.com.

I added a proxy to the curl and I was then able to successfully scrape the page.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);`